# Cancellation token in Task constructor: why?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

Certain `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` constructors take a `CancellationToken` as a parameter:

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task t = new Task (/* method */, source.Token);
```

What baffles me about this is that there is no way from *inside* the method body to actually get at the token passed in (e.g., nothing like `Task.CurrentTask.CancellationToken`). The token has to be provided through some other mechanism, such as the state object or captured  in a lambda.

So what purpose does providing the cancellation token in the constructor serve?

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Passing a `CancellationToken` into the `Task` constructor associates it with the task.

Quoting [Stephen Toub's answer from MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelextensions/thread/c2f614f6-c96c-4821-84cc-050b21aaee45):

> This has two primary benefits:
>
> 1. If the token has cancellation requested prior to the `Task` starting to execute, the `Task` won't execute. Rather than transitioning to
>      `Running`, it'll immediately transition to `Canceled`.  This avoids the
>      costs of running the task if it would just be canceled while running
>      anyway.
> 2. If the body of the task is also monitoring the cancellation token and throws an `OperationCanceledException` containing that token
>      (which is what `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` does), then when the task
>      sees that `OperationCanceledException`, it checks whether the `OperationCanceledException`'s token matches the Task's
>      token.  If it does, that exception is viewed as an acknowledgement of
>      cooperative cancellation and the `Task` transitions to the `Canceled`
>      state (rather than the `Faulted` state).

Answer (score 29):

The constructor uses the token for cancellation handling internally. If your code would like access to the token you are responsible for passing it to yourself. I would highly recommend reading the [Parallel Programming with Microsoft .NET book at CodePlex](http://parallelpatterns.codeplex.com/).

Example usage of CTS from the book:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = cts.Token;

Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    for (...)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        // Body of for loop.
    }
}, token);

// ... elsewhere ...
cts.Cancel();
```

Comment: and what happens if you do not pass token as parameter? Looks like behaviour will be the same, no purpose.

Comment: @sergdev: you pass the token to register it with the task and scheduler. Not passing it and using it would be undefined behavior.

Comment: @sergdev:  after testing: myTask.IsCanceled and myTask.Status are not same when you do not pass the token as parameter. The status will be failed instead of canceled. Nonetheless the exception is the same: it's a OperationCanceledException in both case.

Comment: What if I don't call `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`? In my test, the behavior is the same. Any ideas?

Comment: @machinarium @sergtk: If you pass the token from a `CancellationTokenSource` into a Task constructor, when `cts.Cancel()` is called the Task is going to get canceled and end, no matter what you do (or don't do) in your method body. By default, the canceled Task's status is set to _Faulted_ to indicate it ended **without your consent**. If you monitor for intentional cancellation via `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` the Task's status will be set to _Canceled_ when `tcs.Cancel()` is called, because your code acknowledged it knew about the cancellation request and took appropriate action.

Comment: @CobaltBlue: `when cts.Cancel() is called the Task is going to get canceled and end, no matter what you do` nope.  If the Task is canceled before it has started, it is _Canceled_. If the body of the Task simply never checks any token, it will run to completion, resulting in a _RanToCompletion_ status. If the body throws an `OperationCancelledException`, e.g. by `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`, then Task will check whether that Exception's CancellationToken is the same as the one associated with the Task. If it is, the task is _Canceled_. If not, it's _Faulted_.

Answer (score 7):

Cancellation is not a simple a case as many might think. Some of the subtleties are explained in this blog post on msdn:

For example:

> In certain situations in Parallel Extensions and in other systems, it
>   is necessary to wake up a blocked method for reasons that aren't due
>   to explicit cancellation by a user. For example, if one thread is
>   blocked on `blockingCollection.Take()` due to the collection being empty
>   and another thread subsequently calls
>   `blockingCollection.CompleteAdding()`, then the first call should wake
>   up and throw an `InvalidOperationException` to represent an incorrect
>   usage.

[Cancellation in Parallel Extensions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/cancellation-in-parallel-extensions/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code example that demonstrates the two points in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3713113/10927863) by [Max Galkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2351099/max-galkin):

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*********************************************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("* Start canceled task, don't pass token to constructor");
        Console.WriteLine("*********************************************************************");
        StartCanceledTaskTest(false);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("*********************************************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("* Start canceled task, pass token to constructor");
        Console.WriteLine("*********************************************************************");
        StartCanceledTaskTest(true);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("*********************************************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("* Throw if cancellation requested, don't pass token to constructor");
        Console.WriteLine("*********************************************************************");
        ThrowIfCancellationRequestedTest(false);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("*********************************************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("* Throw if cancellation requested, pass token to constructor");
        Console.WriteLine("*********************************************************************");
        ThrowIfCancellationRequestedTest(true);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Test Completed!!!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void StartCanceledTaskTest(bool passTokenToConstructor)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating task");
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task task = null;
        if (passTokenToConstructor)
        {
            task = new Task(() => TaskWork(tokenSource.Token, false), tokenSource.Token);

        }
        else
        {
            task = new Task(() => TaskWork(tokenSource.Token, false));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Canceling task");
        tokenSource.Cancel();

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting task");
            task.Start();
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("InnerException: {0}", ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Task.Status: {0}", task.Status);
    }

    static void ThrowIfCancellationRequestedTest(bool passTokenToConstructor)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating task");
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task task = null;
        if (passTokenToConstructor)
        {
            task = new Task(() => TaskWork(tokenSource.Token, true), tokenSource.Token);

        }
        else
        {
            task = new Task(() => TaskWork(tokenSource.Token, true));
        }

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting task");
            task.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            Console.WriteLine("Canceling task");
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("InnerException: {0}", ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Task.Status: {0}", task.Status);
    }

    static void TaskWork(CancellationToken token, bool throwException)
    {
        int loopCount = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            loopCount++;
            Console.WriteLine("Task: loop count {0}", loopCount);

            token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(50);
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task: cancellation requested");
                if (throwException)
                {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
*********************************************************************
* Start canceled task, don't pass token to constructor
*********************************************************************
Creating task
Canceling task
Starting task
Task: loop count 1
Task: cancellation requested
Task.Status: RanToCompletion

*********************************************************************
* Start canceled task, pass token to constructor
*********************************************************************
Creating task
Canceling task
Starting task
Exception: Start may not be called on a task that has completed.
Task.Status: Canceled

*********************************************************************
* Throw if cancellation requested, don't pass token to constructor
*********************************************************************
Creating task
Starting task
Task: loop count 1
Task: loop count 2
Canceling task
Task: cancellation requested
Exception: One or more errors occurred.
InnerException: The operation was canceled.
Task.Status: Faulted

*********************************************************************
* Throw if cancellation requested, pass token to constructor
*********************************************************************
Creating task
Starting task
Task: loop count 1
Task: loop count 2
Canceling task
Task: cancellation requested
Exception: One or more errors occurred.
InnerException: A task was canceled.
Task.Status: Canceled


Test Completed!!!
```