# What is the use of passing CancellationToken to Task Class constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, cancellation-token

Here is a sample code that creates a new task that simulates a long running process. There is nothing much on the task as such and purely focuses on the cancelling features. I am using cancellation token to cancel the task and the code works fine for me.

```
CancellationTokenSource CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task<Boolean> PTask = new Task<Boolean>(() => 
{
   while (true)
   {
       if (!CTS.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
       {
          Thread.Sleep(5000);
       }
       else { Console.WriteLine("Thread Cancelled");break; }
   }
   return true;

}, CTS.Token, TaskCreationOptions.None);

PTask.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Hit Enter to cancel the Secondary thread you have started");
Console.ReadLine();
CTS.Cancel();
System.Console.WriteLine(PTask.Result);
```

But one thing that I could not understand is the token parameter (`CTS.Token`) that is being passed on to the `Task` constructor. What is the actual use of passing the parameter, when I can actually cancel the task even without passing token to the constructor.

Down below is a slightly modified version that works without the token parameter.

```
CancellationTokenSource CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task<Boolean> PTask = new Task<Boolean>(() => 
{
   while (true)
   {
       if (!CTS.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
       {
           Thread.Sleep(5000);
       }
       else
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Thread Cancelled");
           break;
       }
};
```

Comment: I would recommend reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/22/9635790.aspx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cancellation token in Task constructor: why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712939/cancellation-token-in-task-constructor-why)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

UPDATE:
The following [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelextensions/thread/c2f614f6-c96c-4821-84cc-050b21aaee45) question describes the reason:

> Passing a token into StartNew associates the token with the Task.
> This has two primary benefits:
>
> 1. If the token has cancellation
>    requested prior to the Task starting to execute, the Task won't
>    execute.  Rather than transitioning to Running, it'll immediately
>    transition to Canceled.  This avoids the costs of running the task if
>    it would just be canceled while running anyway.
> 2. If the body of the
>    task is also monitoring the cancellation token and throws an
>    OperationCanceledException containing that token (which is what
>    `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` does), then when the task sees that OCE,
>    it checks whether the OCE's token matches the Task's token.  If it
>    does, that exception is viewed as an acknowledgement of cooperative
>    cancellation and the Task transitions to the Canceled state (rather
>    than the Faulted state).

Comment: Are you saying the iscancelrequest check with the token of primary thread is unsafe.

Comment: I can not see any other reason of passing token to the constructor, but if you are asking whether i am 100% sure; well not.

Comment: I have updated, in fact this has nothing to do with thread safety.

Comment: Point 2 doesn't seem to be valid. `Task.Run(async () => { throw new OperationCanceledException(); }, new CancellationToken(false)).ContinueWith(tsk => Console.WriteLine(tsk.Status))` returns Canceled, not Faulted.

Comment: @psaxton, I think you need to call ThrowIfCancellationRequested , not thowing the exception yourself. Calling ThrowIfCancellationRequested will pass additional data into the exception, see the source for ThrowIfCancellationRequested, also the same token must be passed to the lambda.