# How to cancel Task so it stops

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am using a Task to read some data from the Database etc. Let's assume I can't change the Dataaccess-API/-Layer.

This dataaccess might sometimes need some time (network-traffic etc.). It will be loaded everey time a user changes a selected item or changes the filter that shows a subset of the aviable data.

At the end I have a little example of my Task-Start-Method.

**My Question is:** If the user changes the filter/selection while the task is still running, how can I stop it from running? When using the cancellation token it will finish (as I am not using a "big" loop in the task, I can't just check every iteration for `.IsCancelled`.

My idea was to use the return type of the Task to fill the `SelectableVolts` and check the returning Task on `IsCancelled` before assigning the new value. But how to do this for an async Task?

```
// added code at the bottom of this question
```

**UPDATE:** After getting comments like "I am not totally sure what your question is asking for, but this should help you get a feel for some avalible options." I will try to clarify my problem a little bit. At least I hope so ;)

1. User selects object in datagrid
2. ViewModel needs data and asks method/class/foo for data.
3. Task(A) is started
4. Task(A) is still working. User selects different object/row.
5. Steps 1, 2 and 3 are repeated. So Task(A) should be cancelled/stopped and a new Task(B) starts.
6. When Task(B) is finished its data should be displayed. In no way Task(A)s data should be made available.

So the question is: How to achieve steps 5 and 6 in a correct way.

**Full Code:**

```
    private CancellationToken cancelTokenOfFilterTask;
    private CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSourceOfFilterTask;

private void FilterVolts()
{
    if (IsApplicationWorking)
    {
        cancelTokenSourceOfFilterTask.Cancel();
    }

    // Prepare CancelToken
    cancelTokenSourceOfFilterTask = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cancelTokenOfFilterTask = cancelTokenSourceOfFilterTask.Token;

    IsApplicationWorking = true;
    if (SelectableVolts != null && SelectableVolts.Count >= 0)
    {
        VoltThatIsSelected = null;
        SelectableVolts.Clear();
    }

    Task voltLoadTask = null;
    voltLoadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<SelectableVoltModel>>(() => {
       VoltsLoader loader = new VoltsLoader();
       Thread.Sleep(2000);
       var listOfVolts = loader.LoadVoltsOnFilter(_sourceOfCachableData, ChosenFilter);
            return listOfVehicles;
        }, cancelTokenOfFilterTask).ContinueWith(listSwitcher =>
        {
            switch (listSwitcher.Status)
            {
                case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
                    SelectableVolts = new ObservableCollection<SelectableVoltsModel>(listSwitcher.Result);
                    IsApplicationWorking = false;
                    break;
                case TaskStatus.Canceled:
                    Console.WriteLine("Cancellation seen"); // Gets never called
                    break;           
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
```

Somehow when I call this Method more than once, all will run in `TaskStatus.RanTocompletion` how can this be possible? Am I doing someting wrong with the cancel-token?

Comment: Please move your own answer out of the question and into an actual answer below (i.e. answer your own question). Then accept your own answer, if it's what worked for you.

Comment: OK - I just wanted to give @Killercam the apprecation for showing me the right way. But you are right maybe the "real" answer would be found fater when marked as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** I think I found a solution, I have to reset the CancellationTokenSource after every cancel-request.

Here is my updated Code based on the accepted answer. If there's something wrong I am happy about any information :)

```
    private CancellationToken cancelTokenOfFilterTask;
    private CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSourceOfFilterTask = new CancellationTokenSource();

    private void FilterVolts()
    {
        if (IsApplicationWorking)
        {
            cancelTokenSourceOfFilterTask.Cancel();
        }

        // Prepare CancelToken
        cancelTokenOfFilterTask = cancelTokenSourceOfFilterTask.Token;

        IsApplicationWorking = true;
        if (SelectableVolts != null && SelectableVolts.Count >= 0)
        {
            VoltThatIsSelected = null;
            SelectableVolts.Clear();
        }

        Task voltsLoadTask = null;
        voltsLoadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<SelectableVoltsModel>>(() => {
            VehicleLoader loader = new VehicleLoader();
            Thread.Sleep(2000); // just for testing, so the task runs a "long" time
            var listOfVolts = loader.LoadVoltsOnFilter(_sourceOfCachableData, ChosenFilter);
            return listOfVolts;
        }, cancelTokenOfFilterTask).ContinueWith(listSwitcher =>
        {
            switch (listSwitcher.Status)
            {
                case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
                    SelectableVolts = new ObservableCollection<SelectableVoltModel>(listSwitcher.Result);
                    IsApplicationWorking = false;
                    break;
                case TaskStatus.Canceled:
                    cancelTokenSourceOfFilterTask = new CancellationTokenSource(); // reset Source
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you cannot include the cancellation support you require in your loop. To do this you just pass the `cancelTokenOfFilterTask` into the method you are calling inside the 'StartNew` delegate. Then inside that method you can do

```
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

To check whether the `Task` was completed sucessfully and deal with the relevent outcome, use a continuation

```
cancelTokenSourceOfFilterTask = new CancellationTokenSource();
cancelTokenOfFilterTask = cancelTokenSourceOfFilterTask.Token;

Task task = null;
task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    VoltLoader vl = new VoltLoader();
    var listOfVolts = vl.LoadVoltsOnFilter(_sourceOfCachableData, ChosenFilter);
    SelectableVolts = new ObservableCollection<SelectableVoltsModel>(listOfVolts);
}, cancelTokenOfFilterTask);

task.ContinueWith(ant => 
{
    switch (ant.Status)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions to prevent UnobservedTaskException.             
        case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
            if (asyncTask.Result)
            {
                // Do stuff...
            }
            else
            {
                // Do stuff...
            }
            break;
        case TaskStatus.Canceled:
            // If Cancelled you can start the task again reading the new settings.
            break;
        case TaskStatus.Faulted:
            break;
    }
}, CancellationToken.None, 
   TaskContinuationOptions.None, 
   TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

I am not totally sure what your question is asking for, but this should help you get a feel for some avalible options.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The idea with the ContinueWith looks very promising. How would I use this in a method? So I call the method `loadNeededData` everytime the user selects another row in a datagrid. When the user changes the row _before_ the old task is finished I need it cancelled. Will every Task run in the same ContiuneWith so I can simply use your switch-statement??

Comment: you don't need to check token.IsCancellationRequested before calling `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` as the method is suppose to raise an exception only `token.IsCancellationRequested` is `true`, the code you wrote is equal to checking the same `token.IsCancellationRequested` twice and then throwing an exception

Comment: See edit... Of course it is a error.

Comment: You will have to create some logical that you set in the continuation upon a cancellation. Then recall the method that you invoked in the first place...

Comment: @Killercam now after the edit it is plain wrong, the `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` will never work, the code you wrote is equivalent to the following code snippet

`if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        throw new OperationCanceledException(token);
    }
}`
how is that correct ?

Comment: Hahaha... What am I doing... Sorry. You are right, I was rushing and on a phone. I will fix this up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to use the [`CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested.aspx) which when called will throw an [`OperationCanceledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception.aspx) if the token had a cancellation request with it

you can use it like this

```
    var cancelTokenSourceOfFilterTask = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancelTokenOfFilterTask = cancelTokenSourceOfFilterTask.Token;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        VoltLoader vl = new VoltLoader();

        //if a request is raised for cancellation then an exception will be thrown
        cancelTokenOfFilterTask.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        var listOfVolts = vl.LoadVoltsOnFilter(_sourceOfCachableData, ChosenFilter);

        SelectableVolts = new ObservableCollection<SelectableVoltsModel>(listOfVolts);
    }, cancelTokenOfFilterTask);
```

the above code is same as the following code snippet

```
    var cancelTokenSourceOfFilterTask = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancelTokenOfFilterTask = cancelTokenSourceOfFilterTask.Token;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        VoltLoader vl = new VoltLoader();

        //if a request is raised for cancellation then an exception will be thrown
        if (cancelTokenOfFilterTask.IsCancellationRequested) 
           throw new OperationCanceledException(cancelTokenOfFilterTask);

        var listOfVolts = vl.LoadVoltsOnFilter(_sourceOfCachableData, ChosenFilter);

        SelectableVolts = new ObservableCollection<SelectableVoltsModel>(listOfVolts);
    }, cancelTokenOfFilterTask);
```

the above is just an example of how it can be used, for more this you can read this SO question about [why Cancellation token is required in Task constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712939/cancellation-token-in-task-constructor-why)

Comment: But will it actually be called if the cancellation follows after the `if-statement`? So its cancelled after `vl.LoadVoltsOnFilter`?

Comment: no, it won't, my advice would be to use that before any heavy operation, you can also same snippet multiple times if you need it

Comment: AFAIK this will not work in all cases. If the Task was cancelled it _can_ happen, that the Task finishes before the last if(isCancelled) returns false. A bad timed context-switch in the parallel execution would be sufficent for this...

Comment: yes, that's what i said in my last comment