# How to transform task.Wait(CancellationToken) to an await statement?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

So, `task.Wait()` can be transformed to `await task`. The semantics are different, of course, but this is roughly how I would go about transforming a blocking code with `Waits` to an asynchronous code with `awaits`.

My question is how to transform `task.Wait(CancellationToken)` to the respective `await` statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancellation Token in await method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822726/cancellation-token-in-await-method)

Comment: Nope, I have seen that one and did not find the answer there. Please, remove the duplication marker, unless explained why are they duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To create a new `Task` that represents an existing task but with an additional cancellation token is quite straightforward.  You only need to call `ContinueWith` on the task, use the new token, and propagate the result/exceptions in the body of the continuation.

```
public static Task WithCancellation(this Task task,
    CancellationToken token)
{
    return task.ContinueWith(t => t.GetAwaiter().GetResult(), token);
}
public static Task<T> WithCancellation<T>(this Task<T> task,
    CancellationToken token)
{
    return task.ContinueWith(t => t.GetAwaiter().GetResult(), token);
}
```

This allows you to write `task.WithCancellation(cancellationToken)` to add a token to a task, which you can then `await`.

Comment: Why not use `t.Result`? So the implementation would be the same for both `Task<T>` and `Task`?

Comment: @I3arnon `Result` doesn't have the correct error propagation semantics.  But the symmetry is nice, yes.

Comment: @Servy - great answer. I have never expected that passing the cancellation token to the continuation actually cancels the task itself.

Comment: @mark It doesn't. It cancels the continuation which you are waiting on.

Comment: @I3arnon - that is what I have thought at first. But this is not what is happening. I have a task that would stay incomplete forever until one explicitly cancels, errors or sets the respective `TaskCompletionSource` instance. And yet, when I trigger the cancellation it does cancel the task. I have a program demonstrating this behavior, see EDIT 3 from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632533/custom-thread-pool-supporting-async-actions (you are quite familiar with that question :-))

Comment: @mark No, it's not.  The method is not causing the underlying task to be cancelled, it's creating a new `Task` that will be canceled without actually cancelling the wrapped task.  Your program is only ever actually inspecting the new wrapping task, not the composed task.

Comment: @mark **only** the continuation is canceled. See this 4 line example: https://gist.github.com/I3arnon/a1de39119f533ea0a943

Comment: Hmm, I see, so the original task is continuing to run in the background with all the possible side effects. Seems like the only possible scenario for `Task.Wait(CancellationToken)` as well as for this extension is to check things and return back `Waiting` or `awaiting` the original task. We should not abandon it to run in the background "out of sight", sort of. Am I right?

Comment: @mark You are correct that the original task is still doing whatever work it has set up to do, and you are quite right that, depending on the task, it may be dangerous to continue executing while that operation is running (it may also be safe, if it is not causing any side effects that would be observable).  You should therefore use this approach with care.  Of course, if you had some way of *actually* canceling the operation you wouldn't need to be doing this.

Answer (score 15):

`await` is used for asynchronous methods/delegates, which either accept a `CancellationToken` and so you should pass one when you call it (i.e. `await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken)`), or they don't and they can't really be canceled (e.g. waiting for an I/O result).

What you can do however, is abandon* these kinds of tasks with this extension method:

```
public static Task<T> WithCancellation<T>(this Task<T> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return task.IsCompleted // fast-path optimization
        ? task
        : task.ContinueWith(
            completedTask => completedTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult(),
            cancellationToken,
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
            TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

Usage:

```
await task.WithCancellation(cancellationToken);
```

---

<sup>* The abandoned task doesn't get cancelled, but your code behaves as though it has. It either ends with a result/exception or it will stay alive forever.</sup>

Comment: Wow, that is unexpectedly involved.

Comment: @mark That's because `async-await` requires a different mindset. "regular" delegate tasks and "promise" async tasks, though they share a type, are quite different concepts... [Two Types of Task](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html)

Comment: +1 for an elegant solution.  I have a virtually identical extension method in my own code base, with the exception that I only bother registering a cancellation callback if `cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled` returns `true`.

Comment: I have some strange situation, where the cancellation callback is not called - please see the EDIT.

Comment: @mark You have some strange and complicated code. You have a race condition in your `InternalTaskScheduler`. Try to run the same example with `Test(false)` in both calls, you'd be surprised at the result. Also try moving the `Thread.Sleep(1000)` to just after `ts.RunInline(t);`. My guess is that if it's fast enough, the thread swallows the `TaskCanceledException` in the empty `catch (OperationCanceledException)`

Comment: @mark I've also added a small example of usage to my answer.

Comment: @mark `Wow, that is unexpectedly involved.` You're quite right.  it doesn't need to be this involved at all.

Comment: @I3arnon - it is a stripped down version of a code using a blocking collection to communicate work to threads. Obviously, it is a bad code... It is related to my other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632533/custom-thread-pool-supporting-async-actions

Comment: @i3arnon Why did you add `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default` patemeters and why it may be better compared to without them?

Comment: @LukAss741 `TaskScheduler.Default` makes sure the continuation will run on a thread-pool thread. `ExecuteSynchronously` is useful for very short tasks. It executes on the same thread instead of re-scheduling on the thread-pool.

Answer (score 3):

From https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#cancelling-uncancellable-operations

```
public static async Task<T> WithCancellation<T>(this Task<T> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);

    // This disposes the registration as soon as one of the tasks trigger
    using (cancellationToken.Register(state =>
    {
        ((TaskCompletionSource<object>)state).TrySetResult(null);
    },
    tcs))
    {
        var resultTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, tcs.Task);
        if (resultTask == tcs.Task)
        {
            // Operation cancelled
            throw new OperationCanceledException(cancellationToken);
        }

        return await task;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

.NET 6 introduced [Task.WaitAsync(TimeSpan, TimeProvider, CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitasync?view=net-8.0#system-threading-tasks-task-waitasync(system-timespan-system-threading-cancellationtoken)), plus related overloads and generics.

```cs
await task.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), cts.Token);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution:

```
Task task;
CancellationToken token;
await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, token));
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49185888/4255615) that talks about using `Task.Delay()` to create a `Task` from a `CancellationToken`. Here are the docs for [Task.WhenAny](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany) and [Task.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay).

Comment: This creates a Task that will never complete.  You would need to cancel the Task.Delay if the task returned from WhenAny is your original task.