# async await task.run xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, async-await, task-parallel-library

I just would like to ensure I understood well the differences between async await and Task.run or Task.whenall

So async await is to process asynchronous methods. It means that there is an order of processing implied.

I run a long processing without blocking the main thread and I wait for the result to continue.

For Task.Run and Task.Whenall there is a new notion with multithreading. It means that I can launch a long process on a new thread and it doesn't wait to complete to continue the code. The code is on a new thread. On this thread then I can await method.

So If I clearly understood I decided to use async await for long processes which implies an order of execution on main thread.

And I use Task.run for thread to run in parrallel and process independently.

Is it the good way and is my understanding good?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of `async`/`await` and `Task.Run` is mostly correct.

`Task.Run` allows you to easily run some code on a [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=netframework-4.8) thread and avoid blocking current thread. Creating multiple `Task`s or using [`Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel?view=netframework-4.8) class allows you take adventage of multiple CPU cores to do some work faster.

When using `async`/`await` you can do some work once your task has completed. Thanks to [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.8) code after `await` can be executed back on your original thread, although it is not always the case. For exaple console application has no [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.8).

One important thing to remember is that `async`/`await` is great for I/O bound work while `Task.Run` is good for CPU bound work. Reason behind this is that when you `await` some I/O bound operation, like sending data over network, you don't waste any thread on just waiting for such operation to complete. You can read more about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method is an easy way to offload work to a background thread. The worker threads are provided by the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) class. Learning a bit about this class is a good idea, to know what happens when the pool becomes starved, and what you can do if you anticipate this to happen (using the [`SetMinThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads) proactively is an option).

Using the `Task.Run` is more convenient than working with `Thread` instances directly. Tasks have a strongly-typed [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result), have an `Exception` property, can be [awaited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) asynchronously, can be [combined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) with other tasks, and can be wrapped in other tasks with extra functionality (for example wrapping a task in a [cancelable wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59243161/is-there-a-way-i-can-cause-a-running-method-to-stop-immediately-with-a-cts-cance/59267214#59267214).