# How to stop all the threads in a page during OnNavigatedFrom method WinRT windows 10?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-10

I am creating a windows 10 app. In a onNavigatedTo I am initializing the content where a bunch of async calls are happening in parallel and when I navigate from the page they continue to run. I want to stop all the async calls before I Navigate from the page as I have common resource and these threads are writing into the common resource even after I navigate from the source page. Is there anyway to do this?
Sample code:

```
foreach(StorageFile sf in list)
{
      StorageItemThumbnail thumb = await sf.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.ListView, thumbnailResize, ThumbnailOptions.ResizeThumbnail);
     //Process the thumbnail and put it in common resouce
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the OnNavigatingFrom Event.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatingfrom.aspx

This event fires right before your page is left. 
Then you can cancle your tasks using the CancelationToken.  See 
[Cancellation Token in await method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822726/cancellation-token-in-await-method) for details how to cancle.

Comment: You sir saved the day! Thank you!