# Why does exist a second parameter of `CancelationToken` type for Task.Run() method?

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks

I try to understand the need for an overloaded method [Task.Run(Func, CancellationToken)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160376(v=vs.110).aspx).

Why does exist a second parameter of `CancelationToken` type, if it is even not passed into the function specified in the first parameter of `Task.Run()` method? There I'm forced to use a closure for this in the `sum` function code. Also, I see the same in Microsoft's code example (look the link above).

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThreadsLearning {
    class Program {

        private static void Main(string[] args) {

            CancellationTokenSource tokenSrc = new CancellationTokenSource();

            Func<int, int> sum = n => {
                int result = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
                    result += i;

                    tokenSrc.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                }
                return result;
            };

            /* Why does exist a second parameter of CancelationToken type, if it
             * is even not passed into the function specified in the first parameter
             * of Task.Run() method?
             * I'm forced to use a closure for this in the 'sum' function code.
             */
            var task = Task.Run(() => sum(30), tokenSrc.Token);

            // I will get the seame result for CancellationToken.None:
            // var task = Task.Run(() => sum(30), CancellationToken.None);

            tokenSrc.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            try {
                Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", task.Result);
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex) {
                foreach (var item in ex.InnerExceptions) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", item.Message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("Other exception (the other 'catch' block): {0}", ex.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hit <Enter> for exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First sentence of the Remarks you linked to - "If cancellation is requested before the task begins execution, *the task does not execute*. Instead it is set to the Canceled state and throws a TaskCanceledException exception." (My emphasis)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712939/cancellation-token-in-task-constructor-why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has two reasons:

- If cancellation is already requested when `Task.Run` is invoked, passing in the `CancellationToken` ensures that your code is never run.
- If your code throws an `OperationCanceledException` from the same `CancellationToken` that was passed in, the task will be marked as canceled rather than failed. Other code may check the task status and change behaviour accordingly.

Comment: You are right, of course. But I don't understand why `CancellationToken` is absent in the callback function signature... This situation forces to me to use closure for this instance. It is not good in my opinion.

Comment: @AndreyBushman Right. There is [an overload of the `Task` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783035(v=vs.110).aspx) (and ditto for [`TaskFactory.StartNew`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780315(v=vs.110).aspx)) that you can use to pass in arbitrary data, including another copy of the cancellation token. It's a pity that there's no corresponding `Task.Run` overload.